# How to put bootstrap button in haml/html file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, haml

I have this link in my haml file:

```
Delete', booking, :method => :delete, :data => { :confirm => 'Are you sure?' }
```

How can I make it into a bootstrap button (I've installed the right gems already)

I know I need to use `%button.btn.btn-default`, but how do I do it with the code above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

have you tried this

```
link_to 'Delete', booking, :method => :delete, data => {:confirm => 'Are you sure?'}, :class => 'btn btn-default'
```

it might have some issue as you are adding button css to link

Comment: %td= link_to 'Delete', booking, :method => :delete, class: "btn btn-danger" worked for me

Comment: but both are same you want how to use class .btn.btn-defaul and I have implemented that not btn-danger , don't you think it is a right answer ?